# How to delete rows from a ndarray object when values inside are equal to?

Tags: python, numpy

My ndarray matrix is X with dimensions (2536,72) is an object type. I want to change the type to float 64, but before I have to delete rows containing ?.

I have used this code but it doesn't work-->

```
import numpy as np
X1=np.delete(X,'?',axis=0)

__main__:2: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer array as obj in delete will result in an error in the future
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-89-34091147b19c>", line 2, in <module>
    X1=np.delete(X,'?',axis=0)

  File "/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4865, in delete
    obj = obj.astype(intp)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?'
```

**Any suggestion for that please??**

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.delete` only works with numbers so `X1=np.delete(X,'?',axis=0)` won't work (`?` is not a number). you have to iterate your first matrix using python list methods, create a new list and then convert it to `numpy` `float` array. something like this (not exactly):

```
x1 = []
for l in x:
    if not l.__contains__('?'):
        x1.append(l)
```

Comment: Mehrdad, thank you. With this piece of code, Python creates a ndarray object (72,) and a matrix X1 with 1848 rows. The code detailed above works  ( my last answer )

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code :

```
rows_to_delete = []                  # a list of all rows to delete
for i in range(0, 3536):             # looping through rows
    for j in range(0, 72):           # scanning all columns in each row
        if (X[i][j] == '?'):
            rows_to_delete.append(i)
            break

for i in range(len(rows_to_be_deleted)):    # deleting unwanted lines 
    numpy.delete(X, (i), axis = 0)
```

Comment: I have used this coderows_to_delete = []                  # a list of all rows to delete
for i in range(0, 2536):             # looping through rows
    for j in range(0, 72):           # scanning all columns in each row
        if (X[i][j] == '?'):
            rows_to_delete.append(i)
            break

for i in range(len(rows_to_delete)):    # deleting unwanted lines 
    np.delete(X, (i), axis = 0)

Comment: you just switched numpy with np because you imported it before as np.
  (   import numpy as np   )
so it is the same. Hope this reveals it.

Comment: with the last code written creating X1 matrix works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, please consider choosing my answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

rows_to_delete = []                  # a list of all rows to delete
for i in range(0, 2536):             # looping through rows
    for j in range(0, 72):           # scanning all columns in each row
        if (X[i][j] == '?'):
            rows_to_delete.append(i)
            break

for i in range(len(rows_to_delete)):    # deleting unwanted lines 
    np.delete(X, (i), axis = 0)
X1=np.delete(X,rows_to_delete,axis=0 ) # creates new matrix X1 with unwanted lines